JavaScript promisses and closures
The following code creates a dummy promise and executes it inside a function.
async function sleep(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, x * 1000);
  });
}

class Run {
  async go(x) {
    console.log('sleep', x);
    await sleep(x);
    console.log('wait up', x);
  }
}

function runner() {
  const r = new Run();
  // Note no `await`
  r.go(1);
  r.go(2);
  r.go(3);

  // Note tha we are NOT returning `r` from this function.
}

async function main() {
  runner();
}

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  return main();
});


The runner() function is not inside another function, not returning anything and not being returned to another caller. So we can assume (can we?) that there is no closure being formed here.
The output of the above script is this:
sleep 1
sleep 2
sleep 3
wait up 1
wait up 2
wait up 3

The promise created inside the runner function seems to outlive function's life. This seems odd. Usually once the function returns, its local variables would be destroyed - but the promise lives on until resolved.
Is this "run to completion" semantics, or something else?

runner is fairly uninteresting. What goes on in Run.go is where the important stuff is happening.

he promise created inside the runner function seems to outlive function's life. This seems odd. Its not odd at all. Variables and the objects they point to are two totally different things.

A call to runner creates 3 promises returned from calling go which are not saved by runner. However the execution context of each call to go is saved on the heap when the await operator is executed.
Notionally at least (I'm not saying how promises are implemented in C++), each context contains resolve and reject functions for the promise execution has already returned. These function pairs must be able to reference the returned promise in order to settle it, and hence prevent the returned promise from being garbage collected - at least until after the outer function body of go returns or throws without being caught.
Note also that if a promise at the head of a promise chain is pending, it can be kept in memory by the resolve/reject function pair it generated to call its executor function, at least until one of the pair is called. If it is resolved with a promise (not settled) it creates a new resolve/reject pair to register on the resolving promise by calling its then method.
So you are correct, runner does not generate a closure of the kind  envisaged that persists after runner returns.
